# is it possible to use a piece of code in a GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

It is necessary to use the following piece of code in a GAMS code repeatedly (I copied this piece of code approximately 10 times or more, in different lines of the program),And has made the program very unreadable.

```
loop(k,s,
                 if( AG(s,k)=TG(s),

                         TG(s)= (TGT(s,k)+2*TGT(s,k-1)+3*TGT(s,k-2))/3  ; );
);
```

Is there a command or a way to use this piece of code more easily?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set up the repeated code with `$onecho` `$offecho`:

```
$onecho > %gams.scrdir%myfile.rsp

loop(k,
     loop(s$flag,
             if( AG(s,k)=TG(s),

                     TG(s)= (TGT(s,k)+2*TGT(s,k-1)+3*TGT(s,k-2))/3  ;
                      flag=0;  );
            );
);

$offecho
```

The `%gams.scrdir%` just saves the file to the scratch directory. (It is then deleted after the run and avoids cluttering up your main directories. You could change this to any path you want.)

To use it in your code:

```
$include %gams.scrdir%myfile.rsp
```

Note that `$onecho` only stores the code in a file; GAMS won’t use the code until you call it with `$include`.

Comment: Hi @ Berenger Thanks so much for solving my problem.  is it necessary to use  `on\off echo` after defining set and parameter `s` ,`k`, `AG` and `TG`? or I can put it every where I want.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be after definitions (in the final compilation). Think of it as simply pasting that code into the file every time you use include. So if you paste it in without having set up the parameters and sets to which it refers beforehand, you will see errors.

Comment: The macro facility could also be an alternative: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_DollarControlOptions.html#UG_DollarControl_MacrosInGAMS